# Python - Construct Class Property - Property Decorator - Strange Behavior

Tags: python, oop, properties, decorator

I am a newbie in object-oriented programing, and I am struggling to understand how to properly construct the property in a class objects.

I encountered an interesting behavior, and I have a hard time figuring it out.

```
class StepCounter:
    def __init__(self, position: int = 0):
        self.position = position

    @property
    def position(self):
        print('Getting At Work')
        return self._position * 2

    @position.setter
    def position(self, position):
        print('Setter At Work')
        if isinstance(position, int):
            self._position = position * 2
        else:
            raise ValueError('Position Argument must be an integer')

    def timer(self, value: int):
        print(value * self.position)
```

After constructing the property `position` in class object `StepCounter`, I did the following

```
# 1: set class instance. 'Setter At Work' printed.
step_instance = StepCounter(-3)

# 2: "Getting At Work" printed & returned -12. As expected.
#    -3 as input, setter multiple the input by 2, and getter multiple the value by 2 again.
print(step_instance.position)

# 3: printed -12 as expected. 
step_instance.timer(1)
```

However, once I mark `position` as a private attribute:

```
class StepCounter:
    def __init__(self, position: int = 0):
        self._position = position
    ....
    all other codes remain the same
```

I got something unexpected:

```
# 1: "Setter At Work" Not Printed
step_instance = StepCounter(-3)

# 2: "Getting At Work" printed & return -6
print(step_instance.position)

# 3: printed -6
step_instance.timer(1)
```

My questions are:

1: it seems like once I marked `position` as a private attribute, the setter is completely skipped. Why does such behavior show up?

2: It seems like, within setter and getter methods for a property, we often use the private attribute with the same name. such as `self._position = position * 2`; then if I want to mark `position` as private in `def __init__()`, what should I do?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: What is `add_number`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems like once I marked position as a private attribute, the setter is completely skipped.

That's exactly what happens. Accessing the attribute directly does not involve the property in any way.

*Only* the methods of the property should access the attribute directly. `__init__` (and `add_number`?) should go through the property like any other user of the property, unless you have a specific reason for accessing the attribute directly.

Comment: Hey @chepner, thank you so much for the explanation! Would you kindly elaborate on `Accessing the attribute directly does not involve the property in any way.`? Also, by `Only the methods of the property should access the attribute directly.`, do you mean in the methods of property, they can only use `self._position` & all other non-property methods can only use `self. position`?

Comment: It's ordinary encapsulation. `_position` is used *by* the property, but is itself no more part of the property than any other attribute. It's the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) that lets you write things like `print(p.position)` and `p.position = 3` instead of something like `print(p.position.get())` and `p.position.set(3)`.